# MESA and Vulkan Packages Not Included in Kububtu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, amd-graphics, opengl, mesa, vulkan

I have had an error with some games running through wine that there are no MESA and/or Vulkan graphics libraries installed (At least this is what I had another user tell me). This first happened when updating from Kububtu 21.10 to Kububtu 22.04, then it happened again on a fresh install of Kububtu.

This was the working solution...

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y wine64 wine32 libasound2-plugins:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386

If possible could someone explain to me why these steps were nessecary?

Specs
Ryzen 3 2200g
16 gb RAM

Comment: Tutorials may not be in scope for this website. It looks like you tried to run an older game through WINE, the system isn't magic, it uses details (including metadata) in an .deb package to work out what other packages to install. The game you had was probably an .exe not installed with `apt` so it doesn't know it needs to find dependencies and has little way to do it. Log messages will sometimes say "can't find library foobar-12.so.1" and then you can `apt-file search` that and install it. Some of yours are default [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgl1-mesa-dri).

Comment: @pbhj While it is an .exe (Roblox) running through wine (Grapejuice), it is a new version of the game. However it (Grapejuice) WAS installed with apt, so the dependencies should have been met automatically as stated on the site, but they were not. To be clear I may have made an error in installing it, but I would have had to make that error before the update on which it still worked. 
  https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/docs/Installing-Graphics-Libraries.html https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/docs/Installing-from-source.html.